# Scala: Read file as infinite/async stream of lines

Tags: scala, file, asynchronous, io, stream

I have a file `/files/somelog.log` that is continuously written to by some other process. What I want to do is to read that file as a (never-ending) stream and respond to it whenever there is a new log line available.

```
val logStream: Stream[String] = readAsStream("/files/somelog.log")
logStream.foreach { line: String => println(line) }
```

So, immediately when the other process writes anther line to the logfile, I expect the `println` above to go off (and *keep* going off).

However, that doesn't seem to be how the default Stream-type works. Scala's Stream isn't async, it's just lazy. What I'm probably looking for is something similar to what akka streams offers (I think). But Akka is so huge (150MB!) - I don't want to pull in so many new things that I don't need just to do something this simple/basic. Is there really no other (tiny!) library or technique I can use?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxScala

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to tail the file you could use [Tailer](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html) from Apache Commons IO:

```
val l = new TailerListenerAdapter() {
    override def handle(line: String): Unit = println(line)
}

val tail = Tailer.create(new File("file.txt"), l)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually recommending this, but you could roll your own.

```
def nextLine( itr: Iterator[String] ): String = {
  while (!itr.hasNext) Thread.sleep(2000)
  itr.next
}
. . .
val log = io.Source.fromFile("/files/somelog.log").getLines
val logTxt = nextLine( log )  // will block until next line is available
. . .
```

Comment: doesn't look very async to me

Comment: Not being `async` isn't the biggest problem with it. It actually doesn't work at all: once EOF is reached, the file is closed, and `hasNext` will never return `true` again.

Comment: It's an interesting suggestion. Too bad it won't work ^. You could always async'ify it manually by putting it in its own thread.

Comment: @Dima, whadyameanitdosntwork??  All my test results are exactly as desired.  It throws an error if the log file doesn't exist, but a more complete implementation would cover that. Try it.  `hasNext` returns `true` after the next line is written to the log. [Wow, harsh audience.]

Comment: @kornfridge, exactly! You can async'ify as desired.

Comment: Tried it out myself now. Does *not* pick up changes I make to the logfile :(  http://pastebin.com/rPKuY0QS   <- Keeps printing out "Waiting..." infinitely. (Mac OSX 10.11.1). Does the same example work for you?

Comment: OK, now I'm confused. @kornfridge, I ran your code in the REPL (2.11.7) on my laptop (Linux 4.2.0-34-generic) and it works fine.  Every time I write a new line to the log (`echo "stuff" >> /tmp/test.txt`) it shows up in the output. As Lewis Carroll put it, "curiouser and curiouser".

Comment: Tried it from the REPL too now. Now it works. _wat!_ :p I need to experiment here -- previously I was running it inside a ScalaFX app I'm making. Could it really affect it. I need to do some more testing. brb

Comment: I found out what caused the varying results now. If you `echo "stuff" >> /tmp/test.txt` it works. If you `vi /tmp/test.txt` and then manually add a line at the end and save, it does _not_ work. Fortunately, the file I'm reading from `echo`-es, so there's hope..!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107426/discussion-between-jwvh-and-kornfridge).